# Declaration is not considered valid

Tags: c++, c, scope

Why is this bad?

```
if (true)
    int stuff = 10;
else
    int stuff = 5;

printf("Stuff is %d\n",stuff);
```

Is it because of scope?

Comment: How about, instead (in a C context where `true` is a variable): __int stuff = true ? 10 : 5;__

Comment: How about, instead: `int stuff = 10;`

Comment: @user: How about `fputs("Stuff is 10\n", stdout);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is tagged both C and C++.  The answer is different in the two languages.

In both C and C++, both branches of an `if` statement must be statements:

`if (`*expression*`)` *statement* `else` *statement*

where the *statement* is commonly a compound statement / block.

In C, a declaration is not a statement, so your code is simply a syntax error. Furthermore, the word `true` is not visible unless you have a `#include <stdbool.h>`. (For that matter, `printf` isn't visible unless you have a `#include <stdio.h>`, but since what you posted is a fragment of a larger program, we can probably assume that.)

You can make the if/else statement valid in both C and C++ by adding curly braces (which is generally good practice anyway):

```
if (true) {
    int stuff = 10;
}
else {
    int stuff = 5;
}
```

Now it becomes a bit clearer that you've declared two distinct variables, both named `stuff`. The scope of each of them ends at the end of the nearest enclosing block; in this case, that's the immediately following `}`:

```
if (true) {
    int stuff = 10;   // stuff is visible here
}                     // and now stuff is no longer visible
else {
    int stuff = 5;    // the other stuff is visible here
}                     // and now is no longer visible
```

After the end of the block, `stuff` isn't just no longer visible. It doesn't even exist, because it's reached the end of its *lifetime*. These are two different things: scope is a region of the program text, and lifetime is a subset of the execution time of the running program. `stuff` is only visible to code after its declaration and before the enclosing `}`. At run time, the object `stuff` exists only until execution reaches the closing `}`.

So yes, the main problem is scope. You have two distinct variables, both named `stuff`, and neither of them is visible to the `printf` call.

To fix this, as the other answers have already said, move the declaration of `stuff` so it's before the if/else statement, and assign to it rather than initializing it.

There are several other ways you can structure the code, depending on what you're trying to do (which is impossible to tell from the code you posted).

Answer (score 8):

Yes. `stuff` only exists in the scope of the `if` and `else` blocks (where they are two different variables). You have to declare it outside the if-else to work.

```
int stuff;

if (true)
    stuff = 10;
else
    stuff = 5;

printf("Stuff is %d\n",stuff);
```

Answer (score 2):

Define you code like this:

```
int stuff;
if (true)
    stuff = 10;
else
    stuff = 5;

printf("Stuff is %d\n",stuff);
```

You can read about c++ scope [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662.aspx).